# Laravel 5 Auth - Change Login Route

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to redirect my user to 'homepage' after successful login.

I've been able to redirect after logout by adding the following to AuthController:

```
protected $redirectAfterLogout = 'homepage';
```

However, adding the following to AuthController does not work after login. It directs me to 'home."

```
protected $redirectPath = 'homepage';
```

I then changed the default redirect in the handle() function in RedirectIfAuthenticated to:

```
return redirect('homepage');
```

Not only does that not work, it gives me the following error:

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve redirecting to 'homepage' after login?

Edit - Adding Routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');  
});

Route::get('home', 'HomepageController@getIndex');
Route::get('homepage', 'HomepageController@getIndex');
```

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: Can you show us your routes file?

Comment: Sure; I'll add them above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by simply modifying the existing Route::get('/') to the following:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomepageController@getIndex');
```

I really didn't need the Welcome View any longer, so this solution made the most sense.

Also, after modifying this Route, I was able to remove my previous 'home' and 'homepage' Routes.

Answer (score 0):

Dude the attribute should be named as `$redirectTo`:

```
 $redirectTo = "homepage";
```

now if you got more than one rule like admin and user, stored within your user model as `type` field, you may override the value of this attribute within `postLogin()` function, override the function first then do your changes. i.e:

```php
    // AuthController.php

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return $this|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
        {
            $user=User::find($this->auth->user()->id);
            if($user->type == "ADMIN")
                $this->redirectTo = "/dashboard";
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        }
        return redirect($this->loginPath())
            ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
            ]);
    }
```

Comment: When I add $redirectTo = "homepage", I get redirected to root, since the following is in RedirectIfAuthenticated: return redirect('/');. If I change that redirect to redirect('homepage'), then I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.